# Is there a way to loop through data based on factor in a column and add up the number of rows?

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation

I have some data in which I have multiple observations of the same event. Based on a threshold of time, I want to condense the observations. But I want to know how many I am condensing (i.e. how many observations become one). I'm not sure how to loop through my dataframe in such a way to do that.

I've tried writing a for loop, if statements, while statements, and have searched tirelessly on google and on stack overflow. Nothing seems to relate to what I need to do.

here is a subset of my data:

```
structure(list(date.time = structure(c(1465877617, 1465877774, 
1465877816, 1465877844, 1465912214, 1465912806, 1465912862, 1465914033
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York"), 
    time = structure(1:8, .Label = c("00:13:37", "00:16:14", 
    "00:16:56", "00:17:24", "09:50:14", "10:00:06", "10:01:02", 
    "10:20:33"), class = "factor"), X = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1), diff_time1 = structure(c(157, 42, 28, 34370, 592, 56, 
    1171, 2820), class = "difftime", units = "secs"), diff_time2 = c(FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), new = c("start", 
    "include", "include", "end", "start", "include", "end", "start-end"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

The goal is to get it to look like below, but with an additional column of sample size for each "smushed" observation:

```
structure(list(n = 1:8, end = structure(c(1465877844, 1465912862, 
1465914033, 1465916853, 1465921999, 1465928992, 1465933159, 1465937668
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), start = structure(c(1465877617, 
1465912214, 1465914033, 1465916853, 1465921999, 1465928647, 1465932867, 
1465937418), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), date = structure(c(16966, 
16966, 16966, 16966, 16966, 16966, 16966, 16966), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(time_since_last = (date.time - lag(date.time, default = first(date.time))) / dminutes(1)) %>%
  mutate(group = 1 + cumsum(time_since_last > 15)) %>% # How many times was there a 15min+ gap? Each new one increments "group"
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(first = min(date.time), # or first(date.time) if sorted
            last  = max(date.time), # or last(date.time) if sorted
            count = n())

## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  group first               last                count
#  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
#1     1 2016-06-14 00:13:37 2016-06-14 00:17:24     4
#2     2 2016-06-14 09:50:14 2016-06-14 10:01:02     3
#3     3 2016-06-14 10:20:33 2016-06-14 10:20:33     1
```

Comment: This is just what I needed! Thank you, Jon Spring! Since I'm new to coding and very much learning, how did you figure that out?

Comment: I heartily recommend the https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ book for an introduction to `dplyr` and related packages. I enjoyed how they made it possible to do lots of useful stuff right away.

Comment: Thank you for that reference. That looks really, really useful.

Comment: quick question - I'm still unclear why you need the cumsum() function in the second line. Haven't been able to crack the reason.

Comment: I wanted to assign each contiguous set of events to a single group. The way I defined "new group" is "has there been a break of 15 minutes or more?" The cumsum line counts how many cumulative times that has happened in the rows up to that point, so everything with `group = 1` is before that has happened yet, everything in `group = 2` is after that has happened once, everything in `group = 3` is after that has happened twice, etc.   (We could also omit the `= 1 +` part, but I liked having the first group be 1 instead of being called group 0.)

Comment: Thank you for that explanations, that really helps me understand that! I've also have been wondering if the way I am binning the data is the best way. Right now it bins observations if they happen within 15 min of each other, but maybe it makes more since to bin observations if they happen within the "first" observation. .. still thinking through it

Comment: I've returned to this and wanted to know if you have guidance on trying to figure out how to calculate the time for the first even in each group. So each even isn't necessarily when there is 15 seconds between each observation, but instead when there is 15 second between that one and the first observation to happen. Hopefully that makes sense!